# Why is my mesh moving away?

Tags: animation, mesh

https://youtu.be/6KdnZn2Wf9M

You can see in the video that the mesh is moving down and separating from the bones when the animation is playing. I deleted the animation and made a new simple animation and the mesh is still moving down.

Comment: you probably have some physics on it

Comment: Do you have physics enabled? It looks like the object is falling due to gravity